# Google Maps: Google Places JS API: getDetails() not returning entire place details

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to show 2 locations on a map that when clicked display all the place details in their respective infowindows. I can only get a return of very limited place details to show, namely the address and that's about it. You can see here: http://www.intermountainvet.com/contact-0. I am console logging the place objects.

I know that there is a robust google place for this business, you can see here: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Intermountain+Pet+Hospital+%26+Lodge/@43.5906437,-116.4033528,15z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x0:0x2a5e055f442189ea!2sIntermountain+Pet+Hospital+%26+Lodge!3m1!1s0x0:0x2a5e055f442189ea

Why can't I access all of those place details to display in my infowindow?

Here is my code. (I have my api key and the libraries=places src in a script tag that I'm not showing here):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 43.618928, lng: -116.274319},
zoom: 11
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

var locA = service.getDetails({
placeId: 'ChIJa_maRXxRrlQRSimVL1yUG8Q'
}, function(place, status) {
  console.log(place);
  console.log(status);
if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('<img src="' + place.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + place.name +
    '<br />Rating: ' + place.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + place.vicinity + '</font>');
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
});

var locB = service.getDetails({
  placeId: 'ChIJow1xfMRUrlQR6ewuO4NvrF0'
}, function(place, status) {
  console.log(place);
  console.log(status);
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<img src="' + place.icon + '" />font style="color:#000;">' + place.name +
        '<br />Rating: ' + place.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + place.vicinity + '</font>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    }
});


}
```

Thanks for looking. I feel like this should be simple and I must be missing something minor.

Comment: Where did you get those place_ids from? They look like they are for the address, not the business

Comment: @geocodezip That may be the problem! I used the placeId finder. But I input the address of the business instead of the business name. Let me try with the business placeId and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: "ChIJa_maRXxRrlQR6okhRF8FXio" looks like it is one of them.

Comment: @geocodezip That was the problem! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the place id for the business (ChIJa_maRXxRrlQR6okhRF8FXio) not the address (ChIJa_maRXxRrlQRSimVL1yUG8Q)